# Nothing happens when I double click on the timer tool on the form

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to add event code to my timer component.

Nothing happens when I double click on the timer tool on the form.

[image]

Comment: The _op_ is trying to find a way to add an event handler from the winforms designer. The question is clear enough once the picture is shown. It should be re-opened to other answers, even though I have the accepted answer. There is something to be said on the lack of feedback the c# winforms designer has for this action, as opposed to the vb.net designer which makes it much clearer what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double click on the (1) below and the designer will create an empty event code

[image: fig1]

For example

1. Double click

   [image: fig2]
2. Designer creates code

   [image: fig3]
3. Empty Event

   ```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
       public Form1()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
       }

       private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {

       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you open the form's properties you should be able to select the element you want to work with in the drop-down list. Select the timer and go to the events tab and create an onTick event.

Comment: There are only ticks in the events section of timer1's properties.

Comment: The op is asking _how_ to create an event from the designer. Most controls support double click on them for the default action, but not the timer event apparently.